# How to correctly use sessions

Tags: php

I have seen a lot of articles on this, but nothing so far has worked. What I want to do is simple.

I have a login page.. verifies who you are through mysql/php, etc. This page has the session_start() in it. From there, it takes you to the menu page.

I want to make it to where if the session hasn't been started from the login page, you're not able to view the menu page and it will direct you back to the login page. If this isn't possible, what I ultimately want to do is make it to where you have to use the login page to view the menu page.

Code from comments:

login.php

```
session_start(); 
session_id ("username");
```

menu.php

```
if(!session_id() == "") { 
    header("location:login.html");
}
```

Comment: Show us what has not worked, and perhaps explain what "has not worked" means.

Comment: This is the latest code I tried. What happens from here is you're still able to view the main page, no errors at all.

login.html
session_start();
session_id ("username");

menu.html
if(!session_id() == "")
{
header("location:login.html");

Comment: "main page" is not php; show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Why are you using `.html` extension? Are you sure PHP is actually being run?

Comment: Why are you using session code in an html file?

Comment: Sorry, the .html is a typo, all of these are in .php extensions

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just starting the session, you should put something inside so that you know it went past `login.php`:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Then, inside the menu page, you also need `session_start()`:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('Location: /login.php');
}
```

Comment: This code essentially worked. Now if I try to go directly to main.php, it directs me back to the login.php

However, after logging in, it still directs me back to the login.php.

Comment: My bad, I had a typo in the code. This worked.. thank you lots

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework such as Laravel as these features are already built in and handled properly. Theres no use reinventing the wheel and a framework such as the one I mentioned is easy to learn.

EDIT: Sorry, i'm relatively new to answering questions so i'll try again.

In libraries such as Usercake, what happens is when the user logs in you set a session variable

```
$_SESSION["stack_user"] = "user@stackoverflow.com"; // This could be their name, an object etc
```

After this on each page that requires the user to be logged in you can check by going

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["stack_user"])){
    header("Location: /login.php");
}
// The rest of your page logic here
```

Aaaaaand I just realised this has already said... boy i'm off to a bad start

Comment: One shouldn't use code one doesn't at least roughly understand, IMO.  He should already have a basic working knowledge of how this stuff works in the first place before he starts relying on a framework to do it for him.

Comment: I understand the he is learning how its done but nowhere did he say this wasn't for a production site. Which like I said, there's no use reinventing the wheel.